# Tkinter transparant frame text is not showing

Tags: python, tkinter, background, widget

I am working on a time widget using python tkinter. I want a transparent frame with text but when I add text to my transparent frame the text is not showing. How do I fix this?
This is my code

```
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()



app.title("Time")
app.geometry("200x300")
#app.wm_attributes("-aplha", 1)
T = tkinter.Text(app, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(tkinter.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
app.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.5)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works for me on OSX

Comment: You can change the background image of the label, to your main window's background color.

Comment: It works fine in my Windows 7 running Python 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

This code adjusts transparency with buttons.

It works well for me. Maybe your computer doesn't support transparency. Try this and see if the text mysteriously disappears, or if it doesn't:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

def more_alpha():
    global alpha
    alpha += 0.05
    if alpha >= 1: # correct alpha to prevent errors
        alpha = 0.99
    update()

def less_alpha():
    global alpha
    alpha -= 0.05
    if alpha <= 0: # correct alpha to prevent errors
        alpha = 0.01
    update()

def update():
    global alpha
    tk.wm_attributes('-alpha', alpha)

alpha = 0.5
update()

Button(tk, text="More visibility", command=more_alpha).grid(padx=25, pady=5)
Button(tk, text="Less visibility", command=less_alpha).grid(padx=25, pady=5)

tk.mainloop()
```